# How many multiprocessing threads can I run at once?

Tags: python

I am making a script that searches a website for keywords. It Is supposed to write all the keywords into a file when It Is done but It Is making a fuzz on line 24. I get this error message `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`.
Now the `find_all` function is in the `bs4` library but since It Is recognizing the `keywords_cols` as a `None` I can't use that function on It. I am uncertain as to why It Is a `NoneType`. Since I define It on line 23. I can not pin-point the problem so here I am.

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def add_plus(keywords):
    keywords = keywords.split()
    keyword_edited = ""
    for i in keywords:
        keyword_edited += i + "+"
    keyword_edited = keyword_edited[:-1]
    return keyword_edited

class KeywordScraper:
        def __init__(self, keyword):
                self.keyword = keyword
                plusified_keyword = add_plus(keyword)
                self.keywords_scraped = []
                self.search_string = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + plusified_keyword
        
        def scrape_SERP(self):
                headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'}
                content = requests.get(self.search_string, headers=headers).text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
                related_keyword_section = soup.find("div", {"class":"card-section"})
                keywords_cols = related_keyword_section.find_all("div", {"class":"brs_col"})

                for col in keywords_cols:
                        list_of_keywords = col.find_all("p", {"class":"nVcaUb"})
                        for i in list_of_keywords:
                                self.keywords_scraped.append(i.find("a").text)

        def write_to_file(self):
            for keyword in self.keywords_scraped:
                    with open("scraped keywords.txt", "a") as f:
                            f.write(keyword + "\n")
            print("keywords related to " + self.keyword + " scraped successfully")

s = KeywordScraper("Best gaming pc")
s.scrape_SERP()
s.write_to_file()
```

Any help would will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Someone, `keywords_cols` contains a `None` value; you have to check each value of `col` to make sure you don't use `col.find_all` when that is true. I'm not sure what any of this has to do with the question in your title.

Comment: Ohh crap, I forgot to change the title xD Thats from an old question that I enver asked.

Comment: (Oh, and I mean "somehow", not "someone". Too late to edit the original comment :) )

Comment: It's not `keywords_cols` that is None, but `related_keyword_section`. If BeautifulSoup is unable to match anything, when you use `find_all` it would return an empty list - not None.